# Rails ActiveStorage is attached? true, but not in rspec expection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I wanna test an action which attaches an image. I use a rSpec request spec.
**The image gets attached in real requests, but the rspec fails** Why?

```rb
  def update_logo
    if params[:logo].present?
      image = params[:logo]
      if image && @current_user.logo.attach(image)
        puts @current_user.logo.attached? # !!! results in TRUE !!!
        render json: @current_user, status: :ok
      end
    end
  end


  it "attaches a logo" do
    post update_logo_url,
      params: { logo: fixture_file_upload(file_fixture('400x400.png'), 'image/png') },
                headers: { "Authorization" => token_generator(user.id) }
     expect(user.logo).to be_attached
   end

expected `#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007fb9f57a90e8 @name="logo", @record=#<User id: 1, name: "....210787000 +0000">>.attached?` to be truthy, got false
```

BTW:

Other tests like ActiveStorage::Attachment.count works
So, this is "green":

```rb
      it 'saves the uploaded file' do
        expect {
          subject
        }.to change(ActiveStorage::Attachment, :count).by(1)
      end
```

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. I slimmed down my whole model and forgot that "shop" part to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading the `user` instance before checking the attachment:

```
expect(user.reload.logo).to be_attached
# ----------^^^^^^
```

You're pulling the `user` out of the database before the request is made. Then the controller method will create its own instance, add the attachment, and save everything. But the `user` in your test won't know about any of that. If you `user.reload`, `user` will be refreshed with the latest information from the database and `user.logo` should be attached.

Comment: Wow, yes, that did the trick. Thank you!!!